# List from a range

Tags: python

How can I input all the numbers from a for loop into a list?

For example:

```
for i in range(0, 5):
    # I want to produce this list: [0,1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: You are close... I think you will find it out if you read the `range` documentation: http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range

Comment: Uh why did you change your question completely? Don't do that, if you have another question, ask a new one. Maybe the official Python tutorial will help you has well: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/

Comment: Are you using python 3? In that case `range` behaves differently.

Comment: Sorry for changing the question... but I realised that I don't want the whole code.. just something to help me to write the code.Didn't tough someone viewed my question so fast. Just regiestered.

Comment: The Python 3 documentation would have helped you as well. Look at all the examples: http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.5/library/functions.html#range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def naturalNumbers(n): 
  return range(1,n+1)
```

For python 3,

```
def naturalNumbers(n): 
  return list(range(1,n+1))
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm using python 3 btw.

Comment: are you sure you *need* a *list*? or just something that's iterable?

Answer (score 3):

Open a python interpreter, and enter:

```
range(0,5)
```

The result may surprise you. Read http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range .

Comment: And in Python3 check out the documentation for `list()`

Answer (score 1):

Felix is right, just use the range(N,M) function.  From the docs ( http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#range ), the first sentence says:

This is a versatile function to create lists containing arithmetic progressions.

Which from your sample code you already know how to use, just didn't realize that it returns a list and it's not part of the for loop itself.

Answer (score 1):

> the problem is that I don't know how to input those numbers into a list

Although the `list(range(1, n+1))` approach is already the best thing you can do, I still do want to answer that question so you can construct different lists later:

```
> myList = [] # create an empty list
> myList.append(2) # append 2 to the list
> myList
[2]
>>> myList += [1] # concat with a single-item list
>>> myList
[2, 1]
>>> for i in range(3, 10, 2): # add multiple items
        myList.append(i)

>>> myList
[2, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the answer hasn't been explicitly given yet:

```
myList = list(range(0,5))
```